# Recorder thumb technique

Tags: technique, recorder

The standard techniques for the left thumb on the recorder involve sliding or rotating the thumb downwards (sometimes using the thumbnail) or rotating/sliding the thumb backwards so that the hole open on the right hand side.
I remember watching a video interview with Michala Petri where she demonstrated her own technique which is to rotate the thumb **upwards** so that the hole opens at the bottom. There seems to be almost no discussion of this on the internet, hence my question: is this technique used by a lot of other professional players, or is it something that almost only she uses? I would have thought that her students, at least, would be using and advocating this method. Or is the general opinion among recorder players that it's too difficult.
The only information I can find is an article in the Feb 2001 issue of the German magazine [Windkanal](http://www.windkanal.de) by a former student of hers, Julie Hedboe. The author describes how she learned this method, but unfortunately give no information on how widespread it is.

Comment: I'd say as long as the movement works for a player, that's all that matters. Opening up the hole the appropriate amount is important, and how that is facilitated is up to the operator.